# How to properly highlight the max value of each row as opposed to the entire range?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, max, conditional-formatting

I am using the following formula to find the highest value in each row:

```
=F5=MAX($F$5:$J$23)
```

But for some reason, it's only highlighting the highest value in the entire selection, and not for each row.

[image: Image of example]

I thought it was because I had blanks, which then I replaced as zeroes, but it still didn't work. I also have the "Applies to" range as the same range in the Max formula.

Comment: `=F5=MAX($F5:$J5)`

Comment: @BigBen would you know how to do the same thing with Min but exclude zeroes/blanks?

Comment: Look at `MINIFS` possibly.